# How do I fix Error: Deployment Failed on ganache?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, metamask, ganache, testnets

I am encountering this error while deploying my smart contract on the Ganache blockchain, can anyone help me fix it?

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Coffee" hit an invalid opcode while deploying. Try:
 * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all assert conditions.
 * Verifying your constructor code doesn't access an array 
 * List item
```

I deployed it on the test net and it showed no error, but when I deployed it on Ganache, it returned this error.

this is my deployment script

```
var MyContract = artifacts.require("coffee");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(MyContract);
};
```

this is my contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract CoffeePurchase {
    address public owner;
    mapping(address => string) private messages;
    struct purchase {
        string from;
        string to;
        address addFrom;
        address addTo;
    }
    purchase[] public purchases;
    event PurchaseMade(address indexed buyer, uint256 amount, string message);

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "Only the owner can access this function");
        _;
    }

    function purchaseCoffee(string calldata _from,string calldata _to,address _addTo,string memory message) public payable {
        require(msg.value > 0, "Coffee price must be greater than 0 wei");
        messages[_addTo] = message;
        purchases.push(purchase(_from,_to,msg.sender,_addTo));
        emit PurchaseMade(msg.sender, msg.value, message);
    }
    function showDetails() external view returns(purchase[] memory){
        return purchases;
    }
    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return messages[msg.sender];
    }

    function withdrawFunds() public onlyOwner {
        payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Solidity? Which network fork in Ganache?

Comment: Please provide your contract code inside your question body, as well as your deploy script.

Comment: @ceseshi i am using solc version0.8.13 and network fork london

Comment: Note to anyone trying to answer: The contract compiles and deploys on Remix while using 0.8.13 solidity and on London fork.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it's solved by doing the following..!

Go to *truffle-config.js* and change the **solc version** to "0.8.0" or "0.8.2" (both worked fine for me)